# all arguments must have the same length in e1071 of R

Tags: r

I can't call function table:

```
table(predict(model,dataset),dataset[,2],dnn=list('predicted','actual'))
```

because a have next error:

> Error in table(predict(model, dataset), dataset[, 2], dnn = list("predicted",  : 
>         all arguments must have the same length

```
class<- ifelse(srz_a>0,"up",ifelse(srz_a<0,"down",0))

dataset<- data.frame(date,class,srz_a)

model<- naiveBayes(dataset[,1],dataset[,2:3])

table(predict(model,dataset),dataset[,2],dnn=list('predicted','actual'))
# Error in table(predict(model, dataset), dataset[, 2], dnn = list("predicted",  : 
#   all arguments must have the same length

dim(dataset)
# [1] 1292    3

class[1292]
# [1] "down"

srz_a[1292]
# [1] -0.0001520257
```

Comment: Your third arugment `dnn=list('predicted','actual')` is a list with 2 elements. This has a different length than the rest of the arguments to `table`

Comment: Thx, I will try